# How to make two different comparing criteria for a class in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, sorting, testing, compare

I have an assignment to make a Country class with two fields(name, capital) which at first has to be compared with another Country based on the name. Afterwards without changing anything I have to make another test which cares only about the capital regarding comparison. How to do two different comparison methods in the same class ? 
This is what I've done so far :

Country class :

```
public class Country implements Comparable {
    private String name;
    private String capital;

    public Country(String name, String capital) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", capital='" + capital + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static final Comparator<Country> nameComparator = (country, secondCountry) -> country.getName().compareTo(secondCountry.getName());

    public static final Comparator<Country> capitalComparator = (country, secondCountry) -> country.getCapital().compareTo(secondCountry.getCapital());


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Method which checks if countries are sorted correctly:

```
public boolean isSorted(List<Country> countryList) {
        boolean sorted = Ordering.natural().isOrdered(countryList);
        return sorted;
    }
```

And my test:

```
  @org.junit.Test
    public void testIfTheListIsSorted () {
        CountryDAO countryDAO = new CountryDAO();
        List<Country> countryList = countryDAO.getCountryList();
        Collections.sort(countryList, Country.nameComparator);
        assertTrue(countryDAO.isSorted(countryList));

    }
```

What do I have to change in order to compare at my choice , whether by name or by capital ? And both ways being testable. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Don't implement Comparable. Provide one of the comparators when sorting, and also provide one of them when checking if a collection is sorted. Note that the comparators could be defined using `Comparator.comparing(Country::getName)`. Also note that, is you had to implement Comparable, don't implement the raw type Comparable. Implement Comparable<Country>.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much Sir ! You were a great help !